# A variable can't actualize

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

Ok so basically I want for fun that everytime someone say menfou in the chat that the bot, it just save in a json file.

```
const menfoumsg = require ("./menfou.json");

/////////

  if (message.content.startsWith ("menfou")) {
    let nmenfou = menfoumsg.menfou
    menfou = +nmenfou + 1 ;

  client.menfoumsg = {menfou}

fs.writeFile ("./menfou.json", JSON.stringify (client.menfoumsg, null, 4), err => {
  if (err) throw err;
})
message.channel.send (`vous avez dit ${nmenfou} menfou!`)

}
```

The problem is that each time, it add 1 but I need to restart the bot so it can actualize

JSON file:

```
{
    "menfou": 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you do a lot of extra data manipulation. The follow code must work.

```
  if (message.content.startsWith ("menfou")) {
      let menfoumsg = require ("./menfou.json");
      menfoumsg.menfou += 1
      fs.writeFileSync("./menfou.json", JSON.stringify(menfoumsg));
      message.channel.send (`vous avez dit ${menfoumsg.nmenfou} menfou!`)
    }
```